# Sending file with POST to server in pure ruby (or library that doesn't need build tools)

Tags: ruby, rest

Writing extensions for Sketchup I need to get around their usage of their own ruby (2.0.0) interpreter. Most importantly, I can't install `gems` that require build tools.

How can I send a  file per POST request to my local server which does some calculations and answers with a JSON object?

I'm aware how I can use `rest-client` to send the file, but due the mentioned restrictions I can't use it (it required build tools). Is there another comparable way or library that can help me?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4403041)?

Comment: @nsave That pretty much worked out of the box, thank you. I only needed to read the file with `IO.binread(filename)`. If you post this as an answer I can accept your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

url  = 'http://foourl.com'
uri  = URI.parse(url)

data = File.read('fil_path')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body         = data
request.content_type = 'audio/amr'

response = http.request(request)
```

(Taken from [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4403041))

Don't forget to configure your content type

Comment: Regarding the content-type, I'm currently misusing this header to get the original file name to my server. Keeping in mind that this is a completely internal REST service, how bad is that?

Comment: @Sven, its not a good idea I think. I'd better send file name as a query parameter

Comment: I'm just thinking like "Why misuse something if we have other simple ways to do that?"

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ruby's native Net::HTTP library.

[Examples](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

or

```
response = http.post('/cgi-bin/search.rb', 'query=foo')
```